# neo4j: where is the graph drawing tool?

Tags: neo4j

This is a copy and paste from the Intro Documentation

*Start by drawing a circle for the node
Add the name Emil*

Yet, I cannot find any tool or place where I can draw a circle within neo4j.
Where would I find the drawing tool?

Comment: Can you post the link of the referred doc?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably referring to either [this github repo](https://github.com/jordanblakey/neo4j-graph-db) or [this slideshare](https://www.slideshare.net/DavidFombellaPombal/neo4j-introduction-basics-cypher-rdbms-to-graph), which are not official neo4j documentation. The author of the above was just saying that you can draw a node on a whiteboard.

You should read the [official neo4j developer manual](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/), which will show you how to actually get started using neo4j.